# Spring 3.1: Have Multiple @Qualifier References Point to Same Bean ID

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, javabeans, autowired

I am working with multiple shared jar libraries that I cannot recompile, and I need them to all use the same bean "StatFactory":

```
<bean id="StatFactory" class="com.tastytoast.helper.StatFactory">
```

All libraries but one correctly use `@Qualifier("StatFactory")`.

```
@Qualifier("StatFactory")
@Autowired
private StatFactory statFactory;
```

Is there any way to get the rebel library which uses `@Qualifer("statFactory")` to link to the "StatFactory" bean?  I have looked online and there does not seem to be mention of it.

For example, something like this:

```
<bean id="statFactory" redirect-to="StatFactory">
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use an alias can do the trick.
An `<alias />` allow you to refer to a named bean with another name

```
<alias name="statFactory" alias="StatFactory"/>
```